# NatTable - Strange behavior when sorting

Tags: nattable

I have a nattable with sort/filter capabilities based off of 
http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=sorting
and example 6031_GlazedListsFilterExample.java

Initially my table has zero rows.

Scenario 1:

- I view a CTabItem that contains a NatTable with no rows.
- If I then populate the rows and click on the column headers, nothing happens (sorting seems disabled).

Scenario 2:

- I do NOT view a CTabItem that contains the NatTable with no rows.
- I then populate the rows
- I then view the CTabItem that contains the NatTable which now has rows.
- I click on the column headers and everything sorts as expected (sorting seems enabled)

Scenario 3:

- I do NOT view a CTabItem that contains the NatTable with no rows.
- I then populate the rows
- I then view the CTabItem that contains the NatTable which now has rows.
- I then remove all row data
- I click on the column headers and everything sorts as expected (sorting seems enabled). * even though there are no rows I still see the up/down icons appear in the column header cell

Is there a reason that the column header actions are not 'updated' after the initial 'view' of the NatTable? In other words, it seems to take the presence/absence of rows into account for the rest of the tables life after the first time the NatTable is viewed, regardless of if the rows change.

Relevant Code sections shown below:

```
private CompositeLayer createExampleLayer(Collection<T> values, 
  IColumnPropertyAccessor<T> columnPropertyAccessor,
  IDataProvider columnHeaderDataProvider, IConfigRegistry 
  configRegistry, Matcher<T> matcher) {
    BodyLayerStack<T> bodyLayerStack = new BodyLayerStack<>(
      values, columnPropertyAccessor);

    // build the column header layer
    DataLayer columnHeaderDataLayer = new 
      DefaultColumnHeaderDataLayer(columnHeaderDataProvider);
    ILayer columnHeaderLayer = new 
      ColumnHeaderLayer(columnHeaderDataLayer, bodyLayerStack,
      bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer());

    SortHeaderLayer<T> sortHeaderLayer = new SortHeaderLayer<>
      (columnHeaderLayer, new GlazedListsSortModel<T>
      (bodyLayerStack.getSortedList(), columnPropertyAccessor, 
      configRegistry,                      
      bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataLayer()), false);

    FilterRowHeaderComposite<T> filterRowHeaderLayer = new 
      FilterRowHeaderComposite<>(
        new DefaultGlazedListsFilterStrategy<T>
         (bodyLayerStack.getFilterList(), columnPropertyAccessor,
         configRegistry),
       sortHeaderLayer, columnHeaderDataLayer.getDataProvider(), 
       configRegistry);

    // Omitted code for rowHeaderLayer and cornerLayer
    return new GridLayer(bodyLayerStack, filterRowHeaderLayer, 
    rowHeaderLayer, cornerLayer);
}

public BodyLayerStack(Collection<T> values, 
  IColumnPropertyAccessor<T> columnPropertyAccessor) {
    eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(values);

    TransformedList<T, T> rowObjectsGlazedList = 
      GlazedLists.threadSafeList(eventList);

    this.sortedList = new SortedList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList, null);

    // wrap the SortedList with the FilterList
    this.filterList = new FilterList<>(sortedList);
    this.bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(this.filterList, 
      columnPropertyAccessor);
    this.bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(getBodyDataProvider());

    // layer for event handling of GlazedLists and PropertyChanges
    GlazedListsEventLayer<T> glazedListsEventLayer = new 
      GlazedListsEventLayer<>(bodyDataLayer, this.filterList);

    this.selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(glazedListsEventLayer);
    ViewportLayer viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(getSelectionLayer());

    setUnderlyingLayer(viewportLayer);
}

private void enableSorting() {
    this.nattable.addConfiguration(new SingleClickSortConfiguration());
}
```

Comment: How do you populate the data?

Comment: lock the eventList and add it directly to that

Comment: And what is the initial values list? An empty list or null?

Comment: An empty list.  Thanks!

Comment: eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(new LinkedBlockingDeque<>());

Comment: The GlazedListsSortModel should deal with that on structural changes. The  question is why is no structural change event fired on applying the first data. You could try to debug if handleLayerEvent() is called. Or try to call refresh() after the first population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the creation of your `SortHeaderLayer` is not correct. The last parameter of the `GlazedListsSortModel` needs to be the `IDataLayer` of the column header, not the body layer.

Changing your code to the following should make things work. It did at least on my side.

```
SortHeaderLayer<T> sortHeaderLayer = new SortHeaderLayer<>
  (columnHeaderLayer, new GlazedListsSortModel<T>
  (bodyLayerStack.getSortedList(), columnPropertyAccessor, 
  configRegistry,                      
  columnHeaderDataLayer), false);
```